# Python zlib-inflate alternative

Tags: python

I have a compressed file which I could uncompress on ubuntu command prompt using zlib-flate as below,

```
zlib-flate -uncompress < inputfile > outfile
```

Here inputfile is a compress file and outfile is the uncompressed version.

The compress file has a byte data.

I did not find the way to do the same using Python.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entire file fits in memory, `zlib` can do exactly this in a very straight forward manner;

```
import zlib

with open("input_file", "rb") as input_file:
   input_data = input_file.read()

decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(input_data)

with open("output_file", "wb") as output_file:
   output_file.write(decompressed_data)
```

If the file is too large to fit in memory, you may want to instead use [`zlib.decompressobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj)  which can do streaming but isn't quite as straight forward.

Comment: Getting below error,
```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/ktawde/work/local_lib/merge_files.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ktawde/work/local_lib/merge_files.py", line 27, in <module>
    decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(input_data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid literal/length code
```

Comment: I found the reason why it is happening. As I am merging file segments together, when I do `cat segments_*` and then try above code it work. However when I try to merge files using Python loop, and then try above code to decompress it, it doesn't work. Any idea what is the difference?

Comment: @KalpeshTawde Can you add your code to the question? It's hard to debug code you can't see :)

Comment: I have found the reason. While merging the segments I am not merging them in correct order.